# can I run the test suite without a web server?

Tags: testing

I'm trying to set up a Test Driven Development environment and I was wondering if it's possible to run the [WordPress test suite](http://unit-tests.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/) without a web server. I'm on a mac (10.7.5) and I've set up phpunit and the mysql server.

Comment: What do you mean by WordPress test suite? WP requires a web server to run, like any website, but you can set up Apache on your localhost.

Comment: You might look at getting MAMP setup. From the looks of it, [this](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) may help you

Comment: @vancoder - I'm talking about the unit tests that are available for phpunit. see: http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/automated-testing for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You're on a Mac! You have two of the three components you need for a Web server by default. Apache and PHP. All you need to do now is get MySQL. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this and can be found with Google.

Of course NW Tech recommendation of MAMP is another great option. Especially if you haven't managed a server before. Check out the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP).

Comment: Looks like he got it working, but he has a new post with issues, see [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97430/how-can-i-debug-my-database-connection-for-unit-testing)

Comment: @Jallits I'm trying to develop in a Test Driven manner so I want to run all of my test from my laptop. I can run tests using phpunit without having a webserver running and I was trying to get the wordpress unit tests running without one either.